# asyncAfter execution block is not called in the serial dispatch queue

Tags: swift, dispatch

I have a serial queue in which I am adding task synchronously. This is to prevent the same function being called at same time from multiple points.

This is my code:

```
var isProcessGoingOn = false
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "co.random.queue")

func funcA() {
    serialQueue.sync {
        if isProcessGoingOn {
            debugPrint("Returned")
            return
        } else {
            isProcessGoingOn = true

            debugPrint("Executing Code")
// This is to mock the n/w call behaviour. In actual code, I would have a n/w hit in this place.
            serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
                debugPrint("Setting isProcessGoingOn false")
                isProcessGoingOn = false

                funcA()
//There may be some cases, where I would need to call the funcA from here.
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's suppose the function is called two times:

```
funcA()
funcA()
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
"Executing Code"
"Returned"
```

Now I was expecting a third call to the funcA, but I am not getting that.
Could anyone explain what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which output you want ?

Comment: Should not "Setting isProcessGoingOn false" be printed along with current output?

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit?

Comment: Moving the async block outside, does call the funcA, but without the specified delay i.e. it is called instantly. And "Setting isProcessGoingOn false" is still not getting printed. I am trying it all on playground. That should not be an issue. right?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code your first method call will execute `debugPrint("Executing Code")` and also set `isProcessGoingOn = true`, At the same time you again call your method funcA(), So it's not wait for your nested block which are:

```
serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
    debugPrint("Setting isProcessGoingOn false")
    isProcessGoingOn = false

    funcA()
})
```

So, above block will never execute due to `deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)` code. Because it's going to wait for 2 second, and before this code execute, your second method call will execute `debugPrint("Returned")` and return from method.

**Solution:**

You need to remove your 2 second delay from your nested block.

**Cons:**

This will affected to your method call second time. It will show you error of execution interrupted.

I hope this will helpful to you and you will fin your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I can't remove the delay as it going to be a network call. After the network call gets completed, I may need to call the funcA again. So could you provide a solution for that?

Comment: Can you explain at where your network call will be completed ?

Comment: So basically, this asyncAfter call is emulating the same behaviour. The call would complete asynchronously and I would get a completion handler and "isProcessGoingOn" would be set to false.

Comment: Have you tried with .nanoseconds(2), I think you adding two second delay taking more time.

Comment: This is not going to be a fixed interval of time anyways as I can't be sure of the time it would take for the network call to finish. Adding  nanoseconds is like executing the code in sync. :(

Comment: I think there would be completion block in your network call, So you need to write this call in there.